# Find lim sup and lim inf of $((-1)^n+1)+1/(2^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Here is what I have, but I do not know if my understanding of lim sup and lim inf are correct:

lim sup= 2
because the smallest sup of the sequence would be $(1+1)+0=2$

lim inf=0
because the largest inf of the sequence would be $(-1+1)+0=0$

Is this the idea or am I off base?

Comment: Hint: it is not too hard to show if $b_n$ is a convergent sequence then $\limsup_{n\to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = (\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n) + (\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n)$ - whether you use the "supremum of limits of subsequences" definition or the "infimum of suprema of tails" definition - and similarly for $\liminf$.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if a proof of that fact is already here somewhere on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, but I don't know what is that you have in mind when you talk about the “smallest sup” and about the “largest inf” of the sequence. The superior limit of the sequence is $2$ because $2$ is the biggest real number which is the limit of a subsequence of your sequence and the inferior limit of the sequence is $0$ because $0$ is the smallest real number which is the limit of a subsequence of your sequence

Comment: Thank you! The way my professor described lim sup is that it is the infimum of a sequence of supremums and lim inf is the supremum of a sequence of infimums, so that is why I was thinking about it in terms of "smallest sup" and "largest inf".